# With softly deleting row boot method of model got undesired operations

Tags: eloquent

In laravel 7 app I make soft deletion with keeping in deleted_by_id, user who deleted it.
Later admin can be able to restyore it or delete permanently
But I encountered that if the model I have boot defined :

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($task) {
        $task_image_image_path= Task::getTaskImagePath($task->id, $task->image);
        deleteFileByPath($task_image_image_path, true);

        foreach ( $task->events()->get() as $nextEvent ) {
            $nextEvent->task_id= null;
            $nextEvent->save();
        }
    });

    static::deleting(function($task) {
        $task->taskAssignedToUsers()->delete();
    });

}
```

I see undesired operations in sql-log:

```
BEGIN;  


Time 3.03 : 
   UPDATE `tsk_tasks` set `deleted_by_id` = '1', `updated_at` = '2020-05-22 14:47:48' 
    WHERE `id` = '4' 


Time 0.77 : 
   SELECT * 
    FROM `tsk_events` 
    WHERE `tsk_events`.`task_id` = '4'     AND `tsk_events`.`task_id` is not null 


Time 8.26 : 
   UPDATE `tsk_events` set `task_id` = '' 
    WHERE `id` = '7' 


Time 0.52 : 
   UPDATE `tsk_events` set `task_id` = '' 
    WHERE `id` = '8' 


Time 0.91 : 
   UPDATE `tsk_events` set `task_id` = '' 
    WHERE `id` = '9' 


Time 16.21 : 
   UPDATE `tsk_events` set `task_id` = '' 
    WHERE `id` = '10' 


Time 0.73 : 
   DELETE 
    FROM `tsk_task_assigned_to_users` 
    WHERE `tsk_task_assigned_to_users`.`task_id` = '4'     AND `tsk_task_assigned_to_users`.`task_id` is not null 


Time 0.48 : 
   UPDATE `tsk_tasks` set `deleted_at` = '2020-05-22 14:47:48' 
    WHERE `id` = '4' 


   COMMIT;
```

which are trigger by boot code.

I run control :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use App\Facades\MyFuncsClass;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'tasks';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    ...

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        if ( ! MyFuncsClass::checkUserGroup([ACCESS_ROLE_ADMIN])) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], HTTP_RESPONSE_NOT_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        $task = Task::find($id);
        if ($task === null) {
            return response()->json([
                'message'    => 'Task # "' . $id . '" not found!',
                'task'       => null
            ], HTTP_RESPONSE_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        $loggedUser          = Auth::guard('api')->user();

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            if(empty($task->deleted_at)) {  // live row to delete softly
                $task->deleted_by_id= $loggedUser->id;
                $task->updated_at  = Carbon::now(config('app.timezone'));;
                $task->save();

                $task->delete();
            } else {
                $task->onlyTrashed()->forceDelete(); // softly deleted row to delete permanently
            }
            // >> App\Post::onlyTrashed()->forceDelete();

            DB::commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();

            return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage(), 'task' => null], HTTP_RESPONSE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        return response()->json(null, HTTP_RESPONSE_OK_RESOURCE_DELETED);
    }
```

As later admin could restore softly deleted row, I dislike that related events lose relation to task row.
How that can be treated? If there is a way in boot to define is it  softly deletion? 
Or some other decision possible here ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found trashed method , like :

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function ($task) {

        if ($task->trashed()) {  // to delete permanently only softly deleted
            $task_image_image_path = Task::getTaskImagePath($task->id, $task->image);
            deleteFileByPath($task_image_image_path, true);
            foreach ($task->events()->get() as $nextEvent) {
                $nextEvent->task_id = null;
                $nextEvent->save();
            }
        }

        static::deleting(function ($task) {
            $task->taskAssignedToUsers()->delete();
        });

    });


}
```

Which is helpfull for me